# post type slug vs page slug

Tags: posts, slug

I having and issue with my permalinks, I wonder if someone has solved this.

Basically I have a page named **videos** and also a post-type name **videos**, so I try to access to /videos I doesnt not display the right content.

Any change I can keep videos as my page slug and also keep videos/video-post-types-links as well???

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You have a clash

Comment: what does your post type registration code look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can created a post template to display the CPT post details (i.e. videos/my-video) and you can create an archive template to display a list of posts (i.e. videos/).

To create a post template in a plugin, add the following to the plugin:

```
function include_templates( $template_path )
{
    if ( get_post_type() == 'videos' )
    {
        if ( is_single() )
        {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array( 'single-videos.php' ) ) )
            {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            }
            else
            {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'single-videos.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_templates', 1 );
```

Then create a template called **single-videos.php** in the plugin folder:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

To create a archive template in a plugin, add the following to the plugin:

```
function include_archive_template($archive_template)
{
     global $post;

     if ( is_post_type_archive ('videos') )
     {
          $archive_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'archive-videos.php';
     }
     return $archive_template;
}

add_filter( 'archive_template', 'include_archive_template' );
```

Then create the **archive-video.php** file on the plugin folder:

```
<?php get_header();

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    // Get Video details
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'vdieos',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $page_args = array(
        'base'         => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => $paged,
        'show_all'     => False,
        'end_size'     => 1,
        'mid_size'     => 2,
        'prev_next'    => True,
        'prev_text'    => __('«'),
        'next_text'    => __('»'),
        'type'         => 'list',
        'add_args'     => False,
        'add_fragment' => ''
    );
    echo paginate_links( $page_args );

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="video_row clearfix">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h3>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">More Details</a>
    </div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    echo paginate_links( $page_args );
    wp_reset_postdata();

get_sidebar();
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.